# PostMessage seems be blocked by other Window's operation

Tags: winapi, windows-xp, windows

It happens only on Windows XP, the Windows API PostMessage will be blocked during maximum or minimum a window of another application. It takes more than 200ms. 
I've set priority of my application to High.
There's no problem on Windows Vista or Windows 7.
Any hints how to solve this problem?

Yun

Comment: Have encountered the same problem on Windows 7, as I understand, it occurs when there is some UI animation in progress, like AnimateWindow or Aero effects. That is sad, have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If that's a problem then call PostMessage from additional thread.

Comment: Yes, I call PostMessage from a working thread instead of main UI thread. Is this a problem?

Comment: No, it could be a solution. So what is the problem? Why are these 200ms so important?

Answer (score 0):

Wait a minute... IIRC, PostMessage has **always** been a non-blocking call. It "posts" and returns immediately. I believe I've tested this in the past. (I'm still waking up so could be wrong.)

If I'm right, there is something else giving the appearance of PostMessage blocking.

Comment: The evidence is if I comment out the PostMessage statement, then everything is back to normal.